# VBA Excel - Как сделать заливку по ячейкам в расширяющемся диапазоне по определенным условиям?

Tags: excel, vba

Здравствуйте, коллеги!

Подскажите пожалуйста: у меня есть макрос, который расширяет количество строк каждый раз на неопределенное значение, то есть диапазон меняется всегда по строкам. И мне нужно закрашивать пустые ячейки, либо ячейки, в которых не содержится текстовой & буквенной информации (символы).

Как это можно реализовать?

Пробовал через isEmpty и isNumeric, но никак не соображу, как можно это сделать в расширяющемся диапазоне по строкам.
Может есть какие-то функции, благодаря которым VBA может обновлять кол-во заполненных строк?

Заранее благодарю!!!

P.S. Пытался здесь посчитать через сложение последних строк в каждом листе

```
            'kolvo_strok = 0
            'With shd
            'lRw1 = shd.Cells(rsh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            'kolvo_strok = kolvo_strok + lRw1
            'End With
            'MsgBox kolvo_strok
```

Comment: *Как это можно реализовать?* Через условное форматирование, например.

Comment: `shd, rsh` - почему поиск в двух объектах (как  понял -  и на листе, и  в диапазоне? ). Строку надо искать на листе, иначе можно получить не то, что ожидаете.### *в которых не содержится текстовой & буквенной информации (символы)* - цифры тоже символы... Что еще может быть в ячейке, кроме символов?

Comment: @Akina не совсем понимаю каким образом можно применить условное форматирование на расширяющемся диапазоне. Нужно выделять пустые ячейки, так что сделать просто $A$1:$AA$1000 не выходит.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCftR.png Само собой после вставки строк надо прибить существующее УФ-правило (оно не будет применено к вставленному диапазону) и пересоздать его.

Comment: @Akina окей, это понятно. Но нельзя ли как-то в правило для УФ засунуть переменную (которая сохраняет количество активных строк в данный момент на листе), чтобы вручную каждый раз не пересоздавать правило?

Comment: @vikttur большое спасибо, описался. Да, теперь код считает количество активных строк. Теперь я могу как-то по условию закрасить в расширяющемся диапазоне ячейки или нет?

Comment: Во-первых, в правило ничего засунуть нельзя. Во-вторых - нахрена? ведь требуемое форматирование не зависит от истории. В третьих, пересоздание правила штука быстрая (вот его пересчёт может быть долгим, если данных дюже дофига).

Comment: А расширять диапазон зачем? Нельзя просто вставить данные? При таком варианте правило  УФ пишется для целого столбца

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Лист1")
    sh.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    With sh.UsedRange
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
            Formula1:="="""""
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Добавление ячеек в диапазон приводит к пересозданию правила и окрашиванию пустых ячеек во всём использованном диапазоне. Если надо не во всём - поправьте, и вместо `With sh.UsedRange` используйте задание в требуемом Range.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Наконец-то разобрался, как эта структура работает.